# Using google locationservices in multiple activities without redundant the code?

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services

Hi All i am using Google location service to get user location. I am using [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates) as reference code and it works fine.But the issue is to use this service i have to call location code in all the activities as i need user location throughout in my app and i don't want to redundant this code in all the activities. So is there any way that i can use it throughout in my app with a single instance of code.

please check my code which i write after Sandy's answer

```
public class App extends Application implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
    mLastUpdateTime = "";
    buildGoogleApiClient();

}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    createLocationRequest();
}
protected void createLocationRequest() {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
    // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
    // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
    // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
    // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            Log.v("=========", "=====@@@@@@===requestCode=" + status.getStatusCode());
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    startLocUpdate();

                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });



}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Class that extends the Application Class if you have not created then write all logic to get the location on application class

Also create a method on the application class that returns you a location object that is fetched from the sample you are referring

e.g.

```
public Location getLatestLocation(){
    return mLocation; //object that you got the location 

}
```

Let me know in case of any issue

Comment: hello Sandy thanks for you reply. i am able to do it :) but having a small issue. you see the google map app i am doing the same to enable geo settings. While doing the codei check in one method i need to pass activity in constructor. Can you please tell me how can i do this. i am adding code in question please check :)

Comment: @user2423768 use the getApplicaionContext() instead of activity there

Comment: @user2423768 let me know if you still have issues

Comment: yes it is giving error, actually  status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS); need activity as parameter.

Comment: Sandy i manage to do it by passing this in the method i called from APP class :) Once again many thanks :)